# How to check model data during Integration testing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, integration-testing, .net-6.0

I'm writing integration tests for an ASP.NET Core MVC app using WebApplicationFactory which provides a HttpClient to make calls against controllers.

This works fine if I just want to check for a success code and a content type:

```
[Fact]
public async Task ViewTestAsync()
{
    var client = mockWebApp.GetClient();
    var response = await client.GetAsync("/Things/View/1");

    response.Content.Headers.ContentType?.ToString().ShouldBe("text/html; charset=utf-8");
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
}
```

But how can I check the model data that the controller returns?

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ViewAsync(int id)
    {
        var res = await mediator.Send(new GetThingCommand { Id = id });

        if (res.Error)
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

        var vm = mapper.Map<ThingVm>(res.Dto);

        return View(vm);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are returning a web page, you will have to parse the HTML and do something with it.

```
var postResponse = await TestClient.PostAsync(posturl, encodedForm);
var postText = await postResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Both `GetAsync` and `PostAsync` return `Task<HttpResponseMessage>`.

AngleSharp is recommended if you need things like CSS style selectors, HtmlAgilityPack is good if you have XPATH queries into the DOM.

Comment: The problem I get with ReadAsStringAsync is that I still don't get the values of the model, I just see their variable names in the HTML e.g. Thing.id instead of the actual id value.

Comment: If your view is faulty, you need to fix that before you can test it.

Comment: The view/model binding is working when I run the app.